# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar datos de un JPasswordField usando un JCheckBox?

Tags: java

tengo problemas al momento de volver a ocultar la contraseña, el código que uso es el siguiente:

```
private void JCB_MostrarContraseñaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
        char i = JPF_Contraseña.getEchoChar();
        if (JCB_MostrarContraseña.isSelected() == true) {
            JPF_Contraseña.setEchoChar((char) 0);
            System.out.println("Activado");
        } else if (JCB_MostrarContraseña.isSelected() == false) {
            JPF_Contraseña.setEchoChar(i);
            System.out.println("Desactivado");
        }
    }
```

De antemano gracias por la atención brindada.

Comment: El problema es que estás guardando el `char i` dentro del propio método... si llamas a ese método cuando ya tienes puesto el echoChar a 0, lo que vas a guardar en ese char es un 0... Una de dos, o pones `*` a mano en el setEchoChar, o guardas el valor en una variable de clase, no dentro del método!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes volver hacer uso de `setEchoChar()` pero le pasas como parametro '*' para que lo vuelva a ocultar.

```
if (JCB_MostrarContraseña.isSelected()) {
        JPF_Contraseña.setEchoChar((char) 0);
        System.out.println("Activado");
   } else  {
        JPF_Contraseña.setEchoChar ('*');
        System.out.println ("Desactivado");
            }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, lo que indicaste me funciono.